# How can i specify one parameter OR another is optional / required using JSDoc?

Tags: jsdoc

It's my first post so I hope you can help!

I have a function that requires one of two different parameters to be provided (either X or Y),  either would be a string. Is there a way to annotate this using JSDoc?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for :
[image: Ctrl + Space to get intellisense]

```js
/** @type {"My first String" | "My Other String"} */
const myStr = "...";
```

?